# opportunity to alert the user when an Opportunity is being closed with no Opportunity line items in it

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new in salesforce and I have a requirement to create a trigger on Opportunity to alert the user when an Opportunity is being closed with no Opportunity line items in it.

Comment: what do you mean alert the user?

Comment: To show error message to user..

Comment: ahh then check Marc's answer that will work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this sample of code. It work for me.

```
trigger opportunitytoopplineitem on Opportunity (before update) {
  map<id,opportunity> allopportunity=new map<id,opportunity>();
 if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate){

    for (Opportunity oppobj : Trigger.new) {

        if((trigger.oldmap.get(oppobj.id).stagename != 'Closed Won'|| trigger.oldmap.get(oppobj.id).stagename != 'Closed Lost') ){
            if((trigger.newmap.get(oppobj.id).stagename == 'Closed Won'|| trigger.newmap.get(oppobj.id).stagename == 'Closed Lost')){
                allopportunity.put(oppobj.id,oppobj);
            }   
                system.debug('allopportunity@@'+allopportunity);
        }
    }

            if(allopportunity.size()>0){

                for(List<OpportunityLineItem> Oli : [select Description,ListPrice,Name,OpportunityId from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId !='' AND OpportunityId In :allopportunity.keySet()])
                {

                    system.debug('oli@@'+oli);
                    if(oli.size() < 1){
                        trigger.new[0].addError('opportunity cannot be closed');
                    }   
                }
            }



 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you ask a question, please do your own research first and post the code you tried so far that it is not working.

Here is a way of achieving you  described:

1) First create a rollup summary field on Opportunity which counts the quantity of OpportunityLineItems associated with the related opportunity

2)  Here is the basic implementation of the trigger ( although you can do it through a workflow easier)

```
trigger Opportunity_Line_Items on Opportunity (before insert, before update)
{

   for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new())
   {
        if (o.isClosed==true &&  o.NumberOfOppLineUp__c ==0) {
          o.addError('No Line Items related to this Opportunity');
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to create a validation rule to prevent them from closing an opportunity if there are no products on the opportunity. This link is good for some useful validation rules for opportunities [Opportunity Validation rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulValidationRules.meta/usefulValidationRules/fields_useful_validation_formulas_oppty_mgmt.htm)

There is a validation rule on that site for "Opportunity Must Have Products if Beyond “Needs Analysis” Stage"

This can be easily adapted for closed won